# rendering only controller-specific stylesheets not working on first request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my application, I have many controllers and tons of css which could potentially be conflicting if plopped all together. Because of this I am linking my stylesheets on a controller-to-controller basis. The Ruby on Rails Guides suggests the following:

> You can also opt to include controller specific stylesheets and JavaScript files only in their respective controllers using the following:
>
> %= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag
>   params[:controller] %>

(I had to omit the first < from <%= because of Stack Overflow block quotes.)

Therefore, here is the resulting head of my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

I have shared css for a navigation bar, which is @import[ed] in my application.css file, and that always works fine. The navigation bar is always styled properly.
The problem is, when I visit a specific page, on the **first** page request, the relevant css to that controller isn't loaded. And in the logs, a request is never made for the controller's stylesheets. But on the **second** page request, it gets styled, and the logs reveal that the stylesheets were requested.

Any reason why this is?

Below is some relevant code to this issue:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */
@import 'normalize';
@import 'sass_vars';
@import 'sitewide';
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700";
```

And in my config/initializers/assets.rb I added all of the names of my javascript and css files to the line

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ......
```

Comment: Remove turbolinks completely from your project. There is like 90% chance that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Does that only involve removing the turbolinks gem?

Comment: It solved my problem, Michal!!!! You should reword your comment and type it as an answer, so I can upvote it and confirm it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Turbolinks, remove it from your project. It includes:

- removing turbolinks gem
- removing requires from application.js and application.css
- removing data-turbolinks-track attribute from your layout

And consider using `rails new --skip-turbolinks` for your next project.